# Specify the order in which MassTransit consumers will consume the same event

Tags: c#, masstransit

I have two consumers: `FirstConsumer` and `SecondConsumer` that consume the same type of event. However, the operations from `SecondConsumer` partially depend on the output of the operations performed by `FirstConsumer`.

Is there a way to ensure that the event will **always** be consumed first by `FirstConsumer` and only after that's done, by `SecondConsumer`?

The quick, ugly way to fix it would be to combine them into one consumer and ensure the concurrency there. However, the consumers have different responsibilities and I would prefer to avoid that.

Another solution would probably be to publish an event as the last operation of `FirstConsumer` and then change the `SecondConsumer` to consume that event instead.

I've also did a quick read on the Automatonymous, however, it doesn't feel like it's the tool for the job.

Is there any way to configure that in MassTransit and enforce the `SecondConsumer` to await till `FirstConsumer` has done its job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it looks like Automatonymous is the way to go.

Basically, what I'm going to implement what is described here: http://docs.masstransit-project.com/en/v2-master/overview/saga.html#combining-events-think-fork-join, that is have the `FirstConsumer` do its job on the occurrence of the same event we already have, but then have it publish another event when it's done. The `SecondConsumer` will wait until both events have completed and only start processing after that.

Comment: Seems like the right way to go, since the second event depends upon the first event being processed, why not just make the second event published by the first event handler publish what's needed for the second event handler, then no need for the composite event.

Comment: Yeah, I could basically republish the event as another event and consume that one in the second consumer, but I feel like the fork/join approach is closer to what should be happening, in terms of architecture. I kinda want to test out the sagas and it feels like a good way to try creating something simple, so :)